# Google error 80048888 while synchronizing GMAIL

Tags: gmail

[image]

I am using lumia 720 and while synchronizing google getting the error. Kindly help.

Comment: Do you synchronise via POP3 or IMAP?

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue? Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

This is [likely](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpemail/what-is-fault-code-80048888/6f7fc4ef-d193-4320-b4fd-4c90576ef6f9) an error that happened because Google updated their SSL certificate. To fix, delete your google account in settings and re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the account then re adding it worked for me, thank you yes...

Comment: Can you describe in your answer how to delete and re-configure the account?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and it's related to the hours/date/time zone parameters. 
Make sure every info is correct. I had a false date on my phone and when I changed it to the actual date, gmail worked again.

Comment: This always happen to me when I turn of my phone with force.